# problem with shell variables in awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a command which is executed successfully on command line:

```
ls -l | awk '/Sep 26/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=1045 && a[1]a[2]<=1145)print $9}'
```

I am including the same thing in a shell script below:

```
#!/bin/ksh

date1=$1
date2=$2
time1=$3
time2=$4
ls -l| awk -v d1=${date1} -v d2=${date2}  -v t1=${time1} -v t2=${time2} '/d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=t1 && a[1]a[2]<=t2) print $9}'
```

But this does not work.please see below the execution

```
ksh -vx test.sh Sep 26 1045 1145
#!/bin/ksh

date1=$1
+ date1=Sep
date2=$2
+ date2=26
time1=$3
+ time1=1045
time2=$4
+ time2=1145
ls -l| awk -v d1=${date1} -v d2=${date2}  -v t1=${time1} -v t2=${time2} '/d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=t1 &&a[1]a[2]<=t2)print $9}'
+ awk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 -v t1=1045 -v t2=1145 /d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=t1 &&a[1]a[2]<=t2)print $9}
+ ls -l
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

I am using Solaris OS:I have tried with nawk now but there is no error but also there is no output.

```
pearl[ncm_o11.2_int.@].293> ksh -vx test.sh Sep 26 1045 1145
#!/bin/ksh

date1=$1
+ date1=Sep
date2=$2
+ date2=26
time1=$3
+ time1=1045
time2=$4
+ time2=1145
ls -l| nawk -v d1=${date1} -v d2=${date2}  -v t1=${time1} -v t2=${time2} '/d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=t1 &&a[1]a[2]<=t2)print $9}'
+ ls -l
+ nawk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 -v t1=1045 -v t2=1145 /d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=t1 &&a[1]a[2]<=t2)print $9}
```

When i am executing with out the shell variables inside the script.its executing perfectly.

**Note:**I am using Solaris OS.

I figured out the problem lies in the final framed command inside shell script:

```
ls -l|nawk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 -v t1=1045 -v t2=1145 '/d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2] >=t1 && a[1]a[2]<=t2)print $9}'
```

But i am not sure why this is failing to give the correct output with -v flags

Comment: `awk --v`. also, does this anything to do with shell variables? does it work if you call it directly without variable substitution?

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested, if you need a dynamic regular expression, you need to use `$0 ~ d1 " " d2` instead of `/d1 d2/`.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system? It's possible that when you run the command interactively *awk* points to a different *awk* implementation. If you're on *Solaris*, for example, try running your script with *nawk* (or *gawk*), instead of *awk*.

Comment: So try using *nawk* in your script.

Comment: At least the error is gone :) I suppose that `/d1 d2/` doesn't mean what you expect. If you need a dynamic regular expression, you need to use something like this: `$0 ~ d1 " " d2`.

Comment: I have observed that the command is not returning any out put.:`ls -l|nawk -v d1=Sep -v d2=26 -v t1=1045 -v t2=1145 '/d1 d2/{split($8,a,":");if(a[1]a[2]>=t1 && a[1]a[2]<=t2)print $9}'`

Comment: Did you try to change `/d1 d2/` to `$0 ~ d1 " " d2`?

Comment: @Dimitre, you have the right answer with `$0 ~ d1 " " d2`: post it as an answer to receive proper credit.

Comment: Thanks Glenn!
(added because of insufficient comment length)